# Join versus select for arrays in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have two ways of dealing with arrays in tables when I am querying Bigquery.  The first is to use a comma-join and UNNEST, and the other is to use an embedded SELECT.  In each case, I am going to pull one entry out of array based on some criteria.  I adapted the BigQuery Working With Arrays example to show what I mean below and at this link: [GBQ](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=1018849548823:4c35e0fc7730471f85987102391cb6cb)

```
#standardSQL
WITH races AS (
  SELECT "800M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" as name),
     STRUCT("Rotich" as name),
     STRUCT("Berian" as name)]
       AS participants
UNION ALL
  SELECT "400M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" as name),
     STRUCT("Rotich" as name),
     STRUCT("Berian" as name)]
)



SELECT
  race,
  (SELECT name from UNNEST(r.participants) where name = "Rudisha" LIMIT 1) as participant
FROM races r;


SELECT  race, participant.name
FROM races r, UNNEST(r.participants) as participant
WHERE participant.name = "Rudisha";
```

The two select statements produce the same output in this example and in the ways I have used them in live code.  One constraint is that I am always only retrieving one item from the array, even if there are multiple items in the array, based on some condition.  My questions are:

1. Is there a performance preference for one technique for large tables with relatively short arrays, often with only one element in the array?
2. Is there a difference in how the queries are structured that might produce different results with more complex or interesting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 a, [1,2,3] arr1, ['a','b','c'] arr2
)
```

What's the result of adding all numbers from arr1?

```
SELECT SUM(a1) sum 
FROM data, UNNEST(arr1) a1
```

The answer is 6. But what if we do this:

```
SELECT SUM(a1) sum, MAX(a2)
FROM data, UNNEST(arr1) a1, UNNEST(arr2)

18   c
```

The answer now is 18 - but that's not correct! Well, it's the correct answer after we do the `CROSS JOIN` with arr2 - but the results surprise us.

So what's the correct way of getting the `MAX` from arr2 and the `SUM` of arr1?

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(a1) FROM UNNEST(arr1) a1)
  , (SELECT MAX(a2) FROM UNNEST(arr2) a2)
FROM data

6   c
```

The lesson here: Avoid "exploding joins" from doing a `CROSS JOIN` between nested arrays - keep them as arrays until you need them.

Comment: If I follow your suggestion, then the point here is that a comma-join can be dangerous because it is a cross join and if you stack it up with more than one join, you might be doing something you don't expect, like your 16 answer.  I think this goes to my second question about unexpected results very nicely, thank you!